# Rails routing how do I constrain my routes id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In my Rails app, I have a path that looks like this: `/events/event_name`. In my routes.rb file, I point any path that matches under `/events/:id` to the same controller. However, what I want to do is constrain that `:id` to only be select choices (i.e. only `marathon` and `swimming` will be allowed to continue and anything else goes to a 404). The actual id processing is taken care of in Angular. Is there a way I can easily constrain my routes without having to list out every single possible choice?

routes.rb:

```
  get '/events/:id' => 'static_pages#event', constraints: {id:[ 'concessions', 'football']} #this doesn't work
```

angular code:

```
app.config([
  '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {  
    // console.log($routeProvider.$get);
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
    $routeProvider.
     when('/events/:id', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/eventTemp.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
     })
  }
]);
```

Edit: To clarify, by "listing out every possible choice" I meant not having to do something like this:

```
get '/events/concessions' => 'static_pages#event'
get '/events/football' = 'static_pages#event'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
get '/events/:id' => 'static_pages#event', constraints: { id: /concessions|football/ }
```

This format takes any regular expression, with the exception that you cannot (and do not need to) include an anchor.  See documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) for more information.